# How to elegantly define shortest happy path between start and end state in a State Pattern design implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, graph, state-pattern

When using state pattern, one is delegating behaviour of the `Entity` to the current `State`.
I have prepared SSCCE that I pasted below. We have an `Entity` which can transition between states : `StartState`, `StateA`, `StateB`, `EndState`. The happy path is simply the shortest path between `StartState` and `EndState`.

In this particual example the shortest happy path is:  `StartState->StateA->StateB->EndState`

I find it hard to express what is the happy path, so I can return the order to the frontend but also be able to navigate myself through. State pattern uses methods not dicitonaries to store nodes end edges, right? I want to avoid just `List<string>`. I'm looking for an elegant solution.

I want to be able to know upfront what is the order of the states in the happy path.

1. Dynamically calculate the shortest path for that class structure?
   XOR
2. Because dynamic calculation is probably hard or very hacky, what is the most elastic/convienient to use way to describe statically the shortest happy path in this state graph?

---

```
namespace States
{
    public class Entity
    {
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public State CurrentState { get; private set; }
        public void Action1() => CurrentState = CurrentState.Action1() ?? CurrentState;
        public void Action2() => CurrentState = CurrentState.Action2() ?? CurrentState;
        public void Action3() => CurrentState = CurrentState.Action3() ?? CurrentState;
    }

    public abstract class State
    {
        protected Entity _entity;

        public State(Entity entity)
        {
            _entity = entity;
        }
        //They return new state or null if transition is illegal
        public abstract State Action1();
        public abstract State Action2();
        public abstract State Action3();
    }

    public class StartState : State
    {
        public StartState(Entity entity) : base(entity) { }
        public override State Action1() => new StateA(_entity); //moves workflow forward
        public override State Action2() => null;
        public override State Action3() => null;
    }

    public class StateA : State
    {
        public StateA(Entity entity) : base(entity) { }
        public override State Action1() => null;
        public override State Action2() => new StateB(_entity); //moves workflow forward
        public override State Action3() => new StartState(_entity); // goes back to StartState
    }

    public class StateB : State
    {
        public StateB(Entity entity) : base(entity) { }
        public override State Action1() => new EndState(_entity); //moves workflow forward to EndState
        public override State Action2() => null;
        public override State Action3() => new StartState(_entity); // goes back to StartState
    }

    public class EndState : State
    {
        public EndState(Entity entity) : base(entity) { }
        public override State Action1() => null;
        public override State Action2() => null;
        public override State Action3() => null;
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you possibly confuse what the state pattern is about. Your implementation of the state pattern is correct, however, the state pattern is not suitable for implementing graph algorithms. In particular, your *State pattern uses methods not dicitonaries to store nodes end edges, right?* is somewhat confusing. In the state pattern implementation, neither nodes not edges are stored anywhere. It's because the transition between two states is purely imperative and can even be non-deterministic (a method can easily transition to two different states behind an `if`).

Comment: So, the state pattern is all about the *behavior* of a state machine. If you need a way to store the information about a graph (and also: compute something that depends on the graph structure), the state pattern is not a suitable data structure.

Comment: @WiktorZychla The separation of logic between states is what state pattern gave me and this is top priority. What I just need to present is the happy path which is predefined.  But let's say if we would like to present whole graph what pattern to use, to maintain behaviour delegation but still be able to traverse the graph?

Comment: To whom you want to present the path? To the graph (code) or to the user? Note that no matter how you store the "happy path" (e.g. as a list), there's no way to determine if the stored path is accurate (corresponds to the code). For example, you can store your list as (Start/B/A/End) where in fact the stored path is invalid (not achievable using actual implementation). But because of the way state transitions are represented (dynamically, as code) there's also no easy way to "compute" the path without either executing the code (but what about any side effects?) or add an extra information.

Comment: If I were you, I would add an extra information to each state (node) - a list of states that is reachable from the node. This way the transition is kind of stored twice, once inside each action methods and then in a list in each node. But having a list of nodes reachable from each node allows you to code any graph algorithm that actually **computes** the path in run time (without executing your action methods but rather just by looking at the transition information). This would go beyond the canonical state pattern implementation but could be your way to go here.

Comment: @WiktorZychla The last post of yours honestly sounds well and addresses the issue from your previous comment(2nd above this comment). Thank you for thinking out of the box about my issue :)! 
Would you be able to provide even a dirty draft in an answer?  
PS: I already extended my state pattern cause I store list of historic states in the `Entity` class.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible approaches here is to go beyond the canonical State implementation and just add an extra information to each state that defines a list of possible transitions.

The motivation here is to have the transition information available *as data* so that it can possibly be used by an extra algorithm that would **compute** the path you want to present to the user.

An approach without this extra information is risky as the only way State keeps the information about transitions is the **code** - each of the Action methods just returns a possible new state. Note however that in cases where there are more possible transitions from a given state (and the actual transition is hidden behind a runtime condition), getting this information in runtime could be tricky.

Consider this

```
public class StartState : State
  public override State Action1() {
     if ( (DateTime.Now.Ticks % 2) == 0 ) {
        return new StateA(_entity); 
     } else {
        return new StateB(_entity); 
     }
  }
```

In this example the start state has two transitions, to A and B, but trying to get this information in runtime could be tricky if not impossible.

Instead, I recommend to just kind of duplicate this knowledge available at runtime and provide an explicit list of states reachable from given state

```
public abstract class State
{
    protected Entity _entity;

    public State(Entity entity)
    {
        _entity = entity;
    }

    //They return new state or null if transition is illegal
    public abstract State Action1();
    public abstract State Action2();
    public abstract State Action3();

    public abstract IEnumerable<State> Transitions { get; }
}
```

and a specific state

```
public class StartState : State
  public override State Action1() {
     if ( (DateTime.Now.Ticks % 2) == 0 ) {
        return new StateA(_entity); 
     } else {
        return new StateB(_entity); 
     }
  }

  public override IEnumerable<State> Transitions { 
     get {
        return new List<State>() { 
           new StateA( this._entity ), new StateB( this._entity )
        }
     }
  }
```

This newly introduced information can be used to compute paths, together with another extra info about a state being the *start state* or the *end state*, you could code a graph traversal algorithm to find a path, all paths, a shortest path, whatever you want.

Depending on how big your graph is and how often it's about to change in future, this approach could be possibly slightly safer than just hardcoding the path into the graph itself (a `List<State>` in your state machine).

I'd only add a string with a description to your state class so that the description can be used in the user interface as a visible representation of states.

```
public abstract class State
{
   public virtual string Description { get; }
   ...
```

Comment: I've awarded the bounty, but I will implement it next week and I will keep you posted how the approach works in practice.

Comment: Thanks, let us know what's your final approach.